# Can I send a MediaStream from a PeerConnection to another?

Tags: webrtc

I'm using Chrome 23.0.1246.0 canary, the latest version.
I want to send a MediaStream that reveived from a client via PeerConnection to another client via PeerConnection.
I mean, the ClientA send its local media stream to me via the PeerConnection between us, and then, I send this media stream to ClientB via the PeerConnection between ClientB and me.

This is my code, but it doesn't work, when I click the AddVideo button for the second time, the "gotRemoteStream" function doesn't be invoked. I don't konw the reason.

Anybody can help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Link</title>
<style type="text/css">
    video { width: 200px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input id="btnAddVideo" type="button" value="Add Video" onclick="AddVideo();" />
<div id="videos"></div>
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    var pcs = new Array();
    var pcr = new Array();
    var mediaStream = new Array();
    var msIndex = 0;
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }, gotStream, function () { alert('get MediaStream Error'); });
    function gotStream(stream) {
        mediaStream[0] = stream;
    }

    var pc1;
    var pc2;
    function AddVideo() {
        if (mediaStream[msIndex] == null) return;
        pc1 = new webkitPeerConnection00(null, iceCallback1);
        pc1.addStream(mediaStream[msIndex]);
        var offer = pc1.createOffer(null);
        pc1.setLocalDescription(256, offer);

        pc2 = new webkitPeerConnection00(null, iceCallback2);
        pc2.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;
        pc2.setRemoteDescription(256, new SessionDescription(offer.toSdp()));
        var answer = pc2.createAnswer(offer.toSdp(), { has_audio: true, has_video: true });
        pc2.setLocalDescription(768, answer);

        pc1.setRemoteDescription(768, new SessionDescription(answer.toSdp()));
        pc2.startIce();
        pc1.startIce();

        pcs.push(pc1);
        pcr.push(pc2);
    }
    function iceCallback1(candidate, bMore) {
        pc2.processIceMessage(new IceCandidate(candidate.label, candidate.toSdp()));
    }
    function iceCallback2(candidate, bMore) {
        pc1.processIceMessage(new IceCandidate(candidate.label, candidate.toSdp()));
    }
    function gotRemoteStream(e) {
        var v = document.createElement('video');
        v.autoplay = 'autoplay';
        v.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
        document.getElementById('videos').appendChild(v);
        mediaStream.push(e.stream);
        msIndex++;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. With the function *addStream* of a *PeerConnection* you can add any *MediaStream* you want. Indeed you have to exchange the SDPs (local and remote description) between the clients once again after adding the stream to the PeerConnection.

Your code is not up-to-date, because since you posted your question there have been a lot of improvment to the api. If you update it with the help of the current [standard](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html), I can help you. :)

Comment: I know, it looks like resurrecting a corpse but still, is there a way to establish peer connection between client (browser) and server (node js) and send MediaStream from server to client?